# How to split data in a csv cell and create new rows

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary, split

I'm uber new to Python.  I have searched through the database and did not find an exact answer to my question.  Here is my basic problem:

I have a csv file of the form:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3   
1, a, DF FD  
2, b, DD FD
```

that I need to write out as a csv in the following form:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3  
1, a, DF  
1, a, FD  
2, b, DD  
2, b, FD
```

Right now I am here with my code:

---

```
import csv  

with open('InputFile.csv', newline='') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')  
    for row in reader:  
        if row[0] != '':  
            print(row)
```

---

I'm using print just to see what I have.  My question now is how do I split the space-separated values in column three and get to the output I am trying to achieve? My actual file is more complicated, but I think an answer to this will get me in the right direction.

Comment: By "need to read", do you mean that you need something which yields the appropriate rows for further processing, or do you want to write out a new csv file?

Comment: yes, sorry the way I wrote it was very confusing

Answer (score 1):

I think the following does what you mean:

```
import csv  
import sys

# Index (starts at 0) of the column that needs to be split up
splitColIndex = 2

with open('InputFile.csv') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')  
    for row in reader:

        # Get the element that needs splitting
        splitElem = row[splitColIndex]
        for subElem in splitElem.split():

            # Iterate over the row elements
            # (actually the indices)
            for idx in range(len(row)):

                # If the column doesn't need splitting, we
                # can just copy it, otherwise we need to use
                # one of the split up values
                if idx != splitColIndex:
                    elem = row[idx]
                else:
                    elem = subElem

                if idx > 0:
                    sys.stdout.write(",")
                sys.stdout.write(elem)

            sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Here, I used the `split` function to transform e.g. `"DF FD"` into a list `[ "DF", "FD" ]`. I also used `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` to have slightly more control over the formatting of the output.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am learning python on my own and things are going slow. I tried to apply this to my file (which has a couple columns after the column that needs to be split) and couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ok I see, I've changed the code a bit so that you can indicate which specific column needs to be split.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the comments.  That really helped to get the for loop nesting.  I was able to tweak the code so that it is suitable for my input file. It prints in the shell (right word?) just the way I want it. Now I need to write to a .csv file instead of the shell.  I'm thinking csv.writer()?

Comment: Isn't it just easier to redirect the output? E.g. "python myprogram.py > newoutput.csv" (without the quotes)